# Selecting rows from R data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I construct a data frame as follows in R version 3.0.2:

```
> name <- c("Bob", "Mary", "John", "Sue", "Paul", "Jane", "Steve")
> age <- c(32, NA, NA, 27, 40, 50, 10)
> sex <- c("M", "F", "M", "F", NA, "F", "M")
> city <- c("New York", "London", "Sao Paulo", "Mumbai", "Sydney", NA, "Beijing")
> census <- data.frame(name, age, sex, city)
> census
   name age  sex      city
1   Bob  32    M  New York
2  Mary  NA    F    London
3  John  NA    M Sao Paulo
4   Sue  27    F    Mumbai
5  Paul  40 <NA>    Sydney
6  Jane  50    F      <NA>
7 Steve  10    M   Beijing
```

I would like to extract all rows where "age" is greater than 30 AND not NA.  It does not matter if other columns have NA.  If I try

```
> na.omit(census[c(census$age>30),])
```

I get the following:

```
  name age sex     city
1  Bob  32   M New York
```

However, this also omits the rows for Paul and Jane which I would also like to return.  The only way I can see doing this is as follows:

```
> foo <- complete.cases(census$age)
> bar <- census[foo, ]
> bar[c(bar$age > 30), ]
  name age  sex     city
1  Bob  32    M New York
5 Paul  40 <NA>   Sydney
6 Jane  50    F     <NA>
```

Is there a more elegant solution to this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about making use of `is.na` in combination to your numeric condition:

```
census[census$age > 30 & !is.na(census$age), ]
#   name age  sex     city
# 1  Bob  32    M New York
# 5 Paul  40 <NA>   Sydney
# 6 Jane  50    F     <NA>
```

The `!` is, of course, `not`.

---

That said, I don't see much problem with your current solution.

---

For "elegance" (a term [I find subjective](http://news.mrdwab.com/2012/12/04/what-exactly-is-elegant-code-in-r/)), check out the "data.table" package:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(census)
DT[age > 30]
#    name age sex     city
# 1:  Bob  32   M New York
# 2: Paul  40  NA   Sydney
# 3: Jane  50   F       NA
```